# Sorting only one property inside an array based on another property

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a Javascript array that has 2 properties `id`, `sortedPosition`.

I want to kind of fake sort the array based on `id`, and modify `sortedPosition` such that it reflects the sorted position of the object within that array.

For example:

Input array:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 34,
        "sortedPosition" : 2
    }, {
        "id" : 3,
        "sortedPosition" : 1
    }, {

        "id" : 344,
        "sortedPosition" : 0
    }
]
```

Output array:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 34,
        "sortedPosition" : 1
    }, {
        "id" : 3,
        "sortedPosition" : 0
    }, {
        "id" : 344,
        "sortedPosition" : 2
    }
]
```

I came upon a solution which looks pretty bad, it involves 2 extra copies of deepCloned arrays, and it doesn't seem right. There has to be a more elegant solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I came upon a solution which looks pretty bad, it involves 2 extra copies of deepCloned arrays

A shallow copy of the array should be enough:

```
arr.slice() // create new array with the same objects
 .sort(function(a,b){return a.id-b.id;}) // sort that (leave original untouched)
 .forEach(function(o,i){o.sortedPosition = i;}); // update the objects
```

Comment: Thanks, your elegant solution is exactly the reason why I summoned SO's help.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array and then update the position.

```
array.sort(function(a1, a2) {
  return a1.id - a2.id;
});

array.forEach(function(v, i) {
  v.sortedPosition = i;
});
```

*edit* if you just want to set the sorted position, you can do something like this:

```
var t = array.map(function(v) {
  return { v: v }
});
t.sort(function(v1, v2) { return v1.v.id - v2.v.id; });
t.forEach(function(v, i) { v.v.sortedPosition = i; });
```

That makes a new array with references to the objects in the original array, then sorts it, then fixes up the position properties. The ordering of the original array is unaffected. The pass to make a new array won't be very expensive; it's not really a "deep copy" at all.

Comment: But this thing is that I don't want the array to be sorted. Just wish to update `sortedPosition`.

Comment: I updated the order of objects in question to avoid this confusion.